# R&D center is closed in career

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm playing with the new ARM stuff, and it's nice. But I tried to load up my research center, and it says it's closed. Some Googling quickly showed me that this happens in Sandbox mode. But my save is definitely a Career mode save. What gives? I need my R&D.

Edit: I managed to overwrite my old persistent save (why does KSP overwrite...) but I have a quicksave! It's just bugged beyond use. I have an in-flight mission but none of the parts or game mechanics (e.g. *gravity*) are working correctly.

Comment: 1.) Are you *sure* your save is a Career mode save? 2.) Is this, by any chance, a pre-0.21 save?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely Career, and no. It's 0.22, which I also played some 0.23, and then just now some 0.23.5.

Comment: Alright, mind uploading your `persistent.sfs` to, say, pastebin? Probably some corrupted Scenario data or similar.

Comment: [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/FwXy799t). I saw some advice about loading an old quicksave, which I did, except the quicksave is in the middle of a flight and the ship is bugged beyond usability- e.g. moving at 0m/s without being pulled in by gravity, parts don't respond to commands, EVA crashes the game, tracking center doesn't recognize the flight, etc.

Comment: Hm, loads perfectly fine for me. Can't find any inconsistencies either. Back up the save folder, reinstall KSP and see if that works.

Comment: Ah, it's my mistake. I loaded the quicksave without backing up my persistent first. I keep forgetting that KSP loads destructively. It's of little concern if the [quicksave](http://pastebin.com/St49M6iN) can load correctly. The quicksave is 295KB and the new persistent save 235KB, even if you just load the quicksave and then exit the game, which I feel is a hint.

Comment: So is it working now?  There was an issue with the update that broke career saves, so that's why it happened.

Comment: The persistent save overwriting my old one from the quicksave seems to be functioning fine, it's just a very long way back in my career and I'd really like my quicksave back :( It's returning from a very long mission with >2000 science and falling right to Kerbin.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the game can fix itself if you give it some time- through time warp. Eventually, the game "notices" that it's started and suddenly gravity and all the parts work again, so I simply loaded the quicksave and tried time warp. After a few seconds at 10k it started functioning again, so I did indeed retrieve my save.